# WPF: Spacing in elements with the use of percent

Tags: wpf

I am trying to create a grid, with some elements, but, I am seeing an space between them (My window is responsive), I create a simple example in WPF to show the problem:

```
    <Grid Background="Red">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="0.20*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="0.80*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="0.20*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid Grid.Row="0" Background="Green" Margin="0">
            <TextBlock Text="Header"></TextBlock>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Row="1" Background="Green" Margin="0">
            <TextBlock Text="Body"></TextBlock>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Row="2" Background="Green" Margin="0">
            <TextBlock Text="Footer"></TextBlock>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

And, let me show you the result:

[image: Result]

As you can see, there is a space between the cells (The background is red), in my real scenario I can't set the background as green (In this example could be a solution).

Is there any way to fill the cells without those spaces (And responsive)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that this issue is due to some rendering problem. If you use `SnapsToDevicePixels="True"`, it should solve your problem:

```
<Grid Background="Red" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="0.20*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="0.80*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="0.20*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Text="Header"  Grid.Row="0" Background="Green"/>
    <TextBlock Text="Body"  Grid.Row="1" Background="Green" />
    <TextBlock Name="Box512" Text="Footer" Grid.Row="2" Background="Green"/>
</Grid>
```